# Unable to install new module in OpenERP 6

Tags: module, installation, new-operator, odoo

I have developed a module 'newpatient' which I am unable to install through a Compressed file folder. I have read the [OpenERP dev. book](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_4_module_development/introduction.html) as well as this [blog](http://www.ibcscorp.com/application-integration-customization/erp/openerp-2/openerp-custom-module-development-quick-start-guide/) on creation of new module. When installing after a copy-paste job from this blog, the module 'notebook' gets installed & working. I apply the same steps (Even checked the code n times now) to my module but still CAN'T get it installed. Even though I get the msg on ERP client ' Modules installed', the module is not in the 'Modules' list. What could be possibly wrong?

Here's the code. the `newpatient.py` file:

```
from osv import fields, osv
import time

class newpatient(osv.osv):
_name = "Newpatient"
_description = "Creating new patient"
_columns = {'name':fields.char('Name',size=30,required=True),
            'address':fields.char('Address',size=50,required=True),
            }
newpatient()
```

The `__init__.py` file:

```
import newpatient
```

The `__openerp__.py` file:

```
{
"name" : "Newpatient",
"version" : "1.0",
"author" : "K Y",
"category" : "Generic Modules/Others",
"depends" : ["base"],
"init_xml" : [newpatient_view.xml],
"demo_xml" : [],
"update_xml" : [],
"installable": True,
"active": False
}
```

Really stuck. Would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure but try with

```
_name="newpatient"
```

To check if the module is installed, go to "Administration / Customisation / Database Structure" and look for newpatient (because it could be your view that isn't well formated)

Tell me if it works...

Comment: I guess that the case was a problem. I created a new module named 'npatient' and put exactly the same names(npatient) in both __openerp__.py & npatient.py & it worked. But the behavior is not consistent. Even when I've repeated these steps for other trial modules, they are not installed. I would do some testing further & let you know, the results. But at least I can explore some features now. Thanks so much for your help :)